# How to apply different filter options for different columns in telerik radgrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

For telerik Radgrid, we are getting default values for filtering columns. But I need to have different filtering options for different columns.

I am able to remove some of the options like this

```
protected void RadGrid1_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    GridFilterMenu menu = RadGrid1.FilterMenu;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < menu.Items.Count)
    {
        if (menu.Items[i].Text == "NoFilter" || menu.Items[i].Text == "Contains" || menu.Items[i].Text == "EqualTo" || menu.Items[i].Text == "GreaterThan" || menu.Items[i].Text == "LessThan")
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            menu.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem here is filter options are getting removed for all the columns. I need different filter options for different columns.
Server side options is preferred. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's funny because the question code sample and the answer came from the same docs.

Comment: I have seen the article. But I need different filtering options for different columns and it is not based on column datatype. For each column I have to give different options based on requiement

Comment: I am trying to get the uniquename inside 'MenuShowing' function. I am able to get the uniquename inside the 'filterMenuShowing' function using the 'eventArgs.get_column().get_uniqueName();'. But that is not working in 'MenuShowing' function. So please help me get the uniqueName in 'MenuShowing' function.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/how-to/Filtering/reduce-the-filter-menu-options

Direct from Telerik:  **This is not possible using server-side code.**  You must use the client-side example from the link above (pasted below):

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var column = null;
        function MenuShowing(sender, args) {
            if (column == null) return;
            var menu = sender; var items = menu.get_items();
            if (column.get_dataType() == "System.String") {
                var i = 0;
                while (i < items.get_count()) {
                    if (!(items.getItem(i).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'Contains': '', 'NotIsEmpty': '', 'IsEmpty': '', 'NotEqualTo': '', 'EqualTo': '' })) {
                        var item = items.getItem(i);
                        if (item != null)
                            item.set_visible(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        var item = items.getItem(i);
                        if (item != null)
                            item.set_visible(true);
                    } i++;
                }
            }
            if (column.get_dataType() == "System.Int64") {
                var j = 0; while (j < items.get_count()) {
                    if (!(items.getItem(j).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'GreaterThan': '', 'LessThan': '', 'NotEqualTo': '', 'EqualTo': '' })) {
                        var item = items.getItem(j); if (item != null)
                            item.set_visible(false);
                    }
                    else { var item = items.getItem(j); if (item != null) item.set_visible(true); } j++;
                }
            }
            column = null;
            menu.repaint();
        }
        function filterMenuShowing(sender, eventArgs) {
            column = eventArgs.get_column();
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

---

```
<telerik:RadGrid...>
    //Additional markup removed
    <FilterMenu OnClientShowing="MenuShowing" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Explanation from Telerik:

> There is a single filtering menu object server-side. Not all of its
>   items appear in every filter menu client-side....The filtering menu is independent for each
>   column in RadGrid - this means that the filtering menu options vary by
>   the DataType of the corresponding column....However, **if you remove some of the options
>   from the menu on the server, this will affect all grid columns and
>   they will be stripped from each column filter menu options (if
>   available by default for that type of column).**

Comment: Thanks. But I need different filtering options for different columns. It is not based on data type. All my columns are GridBoundColums. In that case what modification can I make..?
Do I need to use the uniquename.? 
Could you explain it furthur..?

Comment: I am trying to get the uniquename inside 'MenuShowing' function. I am able to get the uniquename inside the 'filterMenuShowing' function using the 'eventArgs.get_column().get_uniqueName();'. But that is not working in 'MenuShowing' function. So please help me get the uniqueName in 'MenuShowing' function.

Comment: @chambo, You forgot the `<ClientEvents OnFilterMenuShowing="filterMenuShowing" />` thats why Indira fails to solve this issue.

Comment: Its resolved. I got the uniquename in MenuShowing function using column.get_uniqueName() == "uniqueName". Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

### [Chambo solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41507228/6560478) can be customise to solve this exact problem.

#### In Js:

First as you need to access the Column Name, you can add it to the `filterMenuShowing` function. Or access it via `get_uniqueName()` on `column`.

```
var column = null;
var columnName = null;

function MenuShowing(sender, args) {
    if (column == null) return;
    if (columnName == null) return;
    var menu = sender; var items = menu.get_items();
    if (columnName == "Date") { // If the column name is Date
        var i = 0;
        while (i < items.get_count()) {
            if (!(items.getItem(i).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'Contains': '', 'GreaterThan': '', 'LessThan': '' })) {
                var item = items.getItem(i);
                if (item != null){
                    item.set_visible(false);
                }
            }
            else { // Not mandatory.
                var item = items.getItem(i);
                if (item != null){
                    item.set_visible(true);
                }
            } i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (columnName == "Name") {
            var j = 0;
            while (j < items.get_count()) {
                if (!(items.getItem(j).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'Contains': '', 'StartsWith': '', 'EndsWith': '' })) {
                    var item = items.getItem(j);
                    if (item != null){
                        item.set_visible(false);
                    }
                }
                else { // Not mandatory.
                    var item = items.getItem(j);
                    if (item != null){
                        item.set_visible(true);
                    }
                } j++;
            }
        }
    }
    column = null;
    columnName = null;
}
function filterMenuShowing(sender, eventArgs) {
    column = eventArgs.get_column();
    columnName = eventArgs.get_column().get_uniqueName();
}
```

#### In Aspx:

You need to link your function to the right  client event as show in the documentation.

```
<ClientSettings>
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="false" />
    <ClientEvents OnFilterMenuShowing="filterMenuShowing" />
</ClientSettings>
```

and

```
<FilterMenu OnClientShowing="MenuShowing" />
```

Comment: I have tried that already. But I was unable to get the uniqueName inside the 'MenuShowing' function. Anyway Its resolved. I got the uniquename in MenuShowing function using column.get_uniqueName() == "uniqueName". Thanks for the help

Comment: This code works . if  you have trouble getting the uniqueName  in 'MenuShowing' function it's because you forgot to call the 'MenuShowing' function. But it's ok to do it in the "OnFilterMenuShowing".